# Error in NetBean but not an error with javac?

Tags: java

i start reading "java core" book and when i try to compile and run this code

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Console cons = System.console();
    String name = cons.readLine("enter user name: ");
    System.out.println(name); } }
```

first with netbeans 9.0 i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Test.main(Test.java:8)
/home/ahmed/NetBeansProjects/Test/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1328: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ahmed/NetBeansProjects/Test/nbproject/build-impl.xml:948: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

but when i try to compile and run the same code with `javac Test.java` then `java Test`
no errors are generated and the code runs perfectly
what does this means and how to fix it ?

Comment: try eclipse ide... maybe ur in a wrong src folder ?

Comment: You need to seriously read the [`Console` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console()) which states *"The system console, if any, otherwise null."*.  When you've read that, you need to go and read [Java Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/console.html) to understand exactly what the Console is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the javadoc of `System.console()`

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, **if any**.
>
> Returns: The system console, if any,
>   otherwise null.

The console/terminal of Netbeans doesn't support it, so `System.console()` returns null.

Comment: aha i see it now, i think the writer should mention this since he had suggested netbeans at the first chapter and did a small tutorial in how to use it to